# Importing "Reminders" to Google Calendar using CSV file

Tags: csv, calendar, import, google-calendar, reminder

Google has added reminders in place of tasks on the calendar - very nice as they carry forward to the next day if not completed. I'd like to use these more as I have workflows that follow dates before and after a project main date.

What I’m trying to accomplish is this, I would create a list of calculated reminder dates for tasks that get repeated for a project (I’m a photographer and reminders would be based x number of days before and x number of days after the wedding date). I would change the names on the spreadsheet and the dates would be calculated based on the wedding date I input. I would then save it as a CSV and import it into Google Calendar – reminders would come up at the right dates for that wedding and follow me till they were completed – voila…

These are not Events mind you, but reminders.

Is this possible? Can I put something on the CSV that tells Google it’s a reminder and not an event? Is there another (non programming) way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't appear to be possible (yet). You'd think that you'd be able to import a CSV into your Reminders calendar ...

CSV import has a "reminders on/off" option, but that's for sending push notifications, which are not the same as Reminders.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe with a CSV to ICS converter...? (havent looked for one yet, but facing the same challenge)

At the moment i just change the default notifications of the calender before import